# Comparing values with __eq__ in Python

Tags: python, magic-methods

Good day/night, I'm new to Python and I'm making a class called `Alpharange` that works like the range function but with capital letters only. While I was testing to see if the class worked or not I stumbled upon a strange error. When I set `letters1 = Alpharange('D')` and `letters2 = Alpharange('A', 'D')` they printed out the same values like they're supposed to but Python says they aren't equal to each other. To fix this I returned true with the `____eq____` method and while that fixed the error, if I run it with other tests like `letters3 = Alpharange('E')` and `letters4 = Alpharange('B', 'E')` it will return true even though they're not equal to each other.

Here is my class as it stands. Is there a better method to use or a way to use the `other` parameter the same way I can use `self`?

```
class AlphabetRange:
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.for_loop = tuple(args)
        if len(self.for_loop) == 1:
            self.start_point = ord('A')
            self.end_point = ord(self.for_loop[0])
        elif len(self.for_loop) == 2:
            self.start_point = ord(self.for_loop[0])
            self.end_point = ord(self.for_loop[1])
        elif len(self.for_loop) == 3:
            self.start_point = ord(self.for_loop[0])
            self.end_point = ord(self.for_loop[1])


    #Use __iter__ to make obj iterable    
    def __iter__(self):
        if len(self.for_loop) == 1:
            self.start_point = ord('A')
            return self
        elif len(self.for_loop) == 2:
            self.start_point = ord(str(self.for_loop[0]))
            return self
        elif len(self.for_loop) == 3:
            self.start_point = ord(self.for_loop[0])
            return self

    def __next__(self):
        #the_end = self.end_point
        if self.start_point < self.end_point:
            if len(self.for_loop) == 1:
                lets = chr(self.start_point)
                self.start_point += 1
                return lets
            elif len(self.for_loop) == 2:
                lets = chr(self.start_point)
                self.start_point += 1
                return lets
            elif len(self.for_loop) == 3:
                lets = chr(self.start_point)
                self.start_point += self.for_loop[2]
                return lets
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

Comment: What were you using previously as the implementation of your `__eq__` method (the one that wasn't working as intended)?

Comment: In `__eq__` you need to verify that the items in self are the same as the items in other and vis-versa.

Comment: This class doesn't really work like `range` at all. For starters, `range` is not an iterator, which your class is. `range` is a *sequence* so at the very least, you want to support `__getitem__` and `__len__`, `index` etc

Answer (score 0):

By implementing `__eq__` like this you're basically telling python that whatever `other` is doesn't matter, you objects equals it. What you instead want to do is implement actual logic in it:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.start_point == other.start_point and self.end_point == other.end_point
```

Sidenote: my code is ment to illustrate some type of logic which could be used. Please double check how you could tell similar objects apart and use that to determine how `__eq__` should work.

Comment: I was thinking `list(self) == list(other)`.

Comment: @wwii well, that should work, but ideally you'd want to implement `__eq__` in a way that isn't linear. You should be able to do it in constant time